# Xcode 8 can't export archived build for Ad Hoc distribution

Tags: xcode, ad-hoc-distribution

When I try to export my archived app for Ad Hoc distribution in Xcode 8, I get an error message that says:

- that there are **no matching provisioning profiles**, and
- that the existing profiles lack the **application-identifier and keychain-access-groups entitlements**.

[image]

What's the trouble, and how can I get this to work? I've tried generating an Ad Hoc distribution profile at the developer member center, but it isn't helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can archive and export a *new* project, no problem. But I'm having trouble with *this* project, which is an *old* project. Therefore, I think this is a bug in Xcode 8. So the problem appears to be a combination of:

- having **a long-standing existing project**, and
- using Xcode 8's new **automatic codesigning management** feature.

My solution was to *turn off automatic codesigning* for this project. I was then able to specify my downloaded manually generated development profile in both the Signing (Debug) and Signing (Release) sections of the General target editing pane.

[image]

As soon as I did that, I was able to archive and then export that archive for Ad Hoc distribution; during the export, the development profile was replaced by my previously downloaded Ad Hoc distribution profile, and all was well.

One more thing to be careful of here: do *not* use a wild card provisioning profile as the Signing (Release) profile, not even a manually generated wild card development profile. You can (and should) use a development profile, but it must be a development profile targeted specifically to this app.

Comment: The issue has been fixed for Xcode itself. Now, when exporting an archive built from automatically managed project, it is exported correctly. However it seems Xcode Server + Xcode Bot do not support correct resigning when exporting.