# Is there a way to set build settings to default?

Tags: swift, xcode

I spent about 6 hours last night trying to publish my app to the App Store but I get hung up after archiving my project. When I try to validate it before uploading it to the App Store I get an error saying something along the lines of "no provisioning profiles match something something" I've done tons of trouble shooting and I have a bunch of duplicate certificates so is there any way I can start this process from scratch by deleting all im certificates and provisioning profile and setting the build settings to default or do I have to copy and paste all my code to a new project?

Comment: Before you jump off a bridge, check my question and self-answer here; it _might_ help you. But you do not need a new project; I've never had to do that in order to solve one of these provisioning profile problems, no matter how nutty it may get.

Comment: @matt there should be a link in your comment?

Comment: Ooooops. http://stackoverflow.com/q/38062099/341994